# Notification not received if posted during init?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, ios11, swift4

I created an [example project](https://github.com/leanne63/Example-Notifications) to demonstrate the synchronous nature of `Notification` processing.

The notifications process as expected - except when posted during the model's initialization.

[The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4), Two-Phase Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID220) section explains the safety checks for initialization. Here, it says:

> **Safety check 4**
>   An initializer cannot call any instance methods, read
>   the values of any instance properties, or refer to self as a value
>   until after the first phase of initialization is complete.

The first phase of initialization *is* complete in my example before the notification method is called. And, as shown below, I also tried calling the notification directly. Neither is acted upon by the view controller - though when called *after* initialization, the view controller does respond as expected.

Is this a bug I should be reporting? Or am I just having a brain-dead moment on something simple regarding initialization?

Here's the relevant model code:

```
class Model {

    let notificationONEName = Notification.Name("NotificationONE")
    let notificationTWOName = Notification.Name("NotificationTWO")

    init() {
        notifyObserversTWO()
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationTWOName, object: self)
    }

    func notifyObserversONE() {
        print("START \(Model.self).\(#function)")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationONEName, object: self)
        print("END \(Model.self).\(#function)")
    }
}
```

And, here's the observer-side code in the view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let notificationONESelector = #selector(didReceiveNotificationONE)
    let notificationTWOSelector = #selector(didReceiveNotificationTWO)

    let model = Model()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        subscribeToNotifications()
        model.notifyObserversONE()
        model.notifyObserversTWO()
    }

    func subscribeToNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: notificationONESelector,
                                           name: model.notificationONEName,
                                           object: model)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: notificationTWOSelector,
                                           name: model.notificationTWOName,
                                           object: nil)
    }

    @objc func didReceiveNotificationONE(notification: Notification) {
        print("START \(ViewController.self).\(#function)")
        exampleUtilityFunction()
        print("END \(ViewController.self).\(#function)")
    }

    @objc func didReceiveNotificationTWO(notification: Notification) {
        print("START \(ViewController.self).\(#function)")
        exampleUtilityFunction()
        print("END \(ViewController.self).\(#function)")
    }

    func exampleUtilityFunction() {
        print("START \(ViewController.self).\(#function)")
        print("END \(ViewController.self).\(#function)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point that `Model.init` is called, nothing is observing it. You don't call `subscribeToNotifications` until long after the call to `Model()`.

If you wanted to respond to this notification, you would first need to observe `object: nil` (as you have for the second notification) before `init` is called. That means you can't initialize it in the property definition. You would need call `subscribeToNotifications` and then create `model`.

Comment: AND I wouldn't be able to retrieve the notification name constants from the model either. Duh. Definitely a brain-dead moment! Thanks, Rob.